# Make Changes {Resize} in Linux Installed Partittion

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have installed LINUX in sda1 Partition. I don't have any other operating system other than linux in my PC. Now i want to install some other operation system and sadly I don't have enough space in other drives.

I currently have 100MB allocated for linux but I think for my use 30GB will be enough, so I want to shrink the sda1 partition by 70GB.

Is it possible to resize sda1 partition without disturbing the files and my linux operating system ?

Here's a screenshot of my setup: [image: i.stack.imgur.com/dbW11.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is.  However, you can't do it from your current operating system, you need to boot into a live environment (like a LiveCD, LiveUSB etc).

Look for a LiveCD with GParted on it, which is a graphical partition editor.  From there, you can select your partition and shrink it.  You want to backup any critical data on there, in case something goes wrong, and make sure there's enough free space to shrink it to where you want.  Make sure you don't interrupt it once the shrink is in progress or things will be bad.

I believe every Ubuntu LiveCD has GParted on it. [Here](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) you can find GParted Live, which is exactly that; a live environment with nothing but GParted on it.

Good luck, make sure you look into what you need to do once you've installed the other operating system.  If it's another Linux distribution, it will most likely detect your current one.  If it's Windows, you'll have to get a Linux LiveCD again to reinstall the bootloader (which is outside the scope of this question, but there's plenty of information around on how to do that).